# Parse error: Unknown Class PFImageView in Interface Builder file

Tags: swift, parse-platform, parseui, pfimageview

I implemented Parse and ParseUI, and successfully use the PFImageView, load images without any error. But suddenly I encounter:

> Unknown class _TtC6Roster11PFImageView in Interface Builder file.

I have searched for similar error, and I found some:

I have tried:

```
PFImageView.self
```

...in Application delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Comment: I managed to solve this issue by switching the target device to simulator. What I have noticed in the xcode's identity inspector, the module name below class name (PFImageView) was replaced to `none`, supposed to be the module name where PFImageView is located. I run, and it worked in simulator, then I changed to actual device and error also gone. Glad if Anyone could explain this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Xcode is a large, complicated application with many bugs. So often many of these seemingly random issues can be temporarily solved by restarting Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the bad reference is due to Xcode storing bad IB data. You will experience similar issues if you delete IB objects (especially Xibs) or if you start working with other people on projects and are pulling/pushing updated code.

One of the simplest things to try (that generally solves these issues) is to perform a `clean` (build -> clean, or <kbd>⇧⌘K</kbd>). This "Removes all the product files, as well as any object files (.o files) or other intermediate files created during the build process ([glossary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/Xcode_Glossary/20-Glossary/Glossary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007993-CH3-SW25))" and works pretty well.